# Getting the shareable link to a channel message using Slack API

Tags: slack-api, slack

Is there any way for me to get the shareable link to a slack message which has been posted in a slack channel.

I looked into their web API but couldn't find any documentation that can give me the message link using the message ts (time stamp).

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Never mind, was able to figure it out.

For anyone interested, The shareable URL is actually nothing but the combination of the channel id and the message time stamp.

It looks like following (don't miss the "p" before timestamp in url):

```
https://domain.slack.com/archives/CHANNEL_ID/pMESSAGE_TIME_STAMP_WITHOUT_ANY_DOTS
```

Comment: what if there are multiple messages sent at the same time to the same channel?

Answer (score 1):

The proposed solution is still working and anyone should be able to build the shareable link by simply combining channel ID and the message timestamp (as described in the accepted answer). However, instead of trying to rely on some internal stuff, I would recommend using [getPermalink](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.getPermalink) method.

For example, in [Python](https://pypi.org/project/slack-sdk/) you could write sth like:

```py
from slack_sdk import WebClient

slack_client = WebClient(token=YOUR_SLACK_TOKEN)
response = slack_client.chat_getPermalink(channel=CHANNEL_ID, message_ts=MESSAGE_TS)
response.data["permalink"]
# https://domain.slack.com/archives/CHANNEL_ID/...
```